# CRA в продакшне

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, app, bundles

Стоит ли использовать create react app в проде? Не будет ли приложение тормозить из-за лишних пакетов? Или при самостоятельной настройке их станет также много? Был ли у вас опыт с CRA в проде?

Comment: А чем это должно всё мешать проду? Это же тупо бандл, подобный Вы и сами соберете. Ну порежьте какие-то пакеты, если они Вас сильно смущают...

Comment: Дело в том что я первый раз делаю проект для клиента. В гугле одни пишут что cra для большего чем мини проектов не годится и лучше самому всё настроить. А мой проект достаточно большой, хотелось бы сразу правильно начать делать, чтобы в конце не пришлось страдать

Comment: Честно, не знаю прям вообще всех тонкостей React, но CRA и стартер-паки больше помогают собрать всё без вспоминания, что нужно поставить ещё было в новый проект. Даже если и будет что-то лишнее, то вряд ли оно будет сильно влиять на производительность. Пробегитесь по списку зависимостей, посмотрите, что точно не используется, и удалите. Ну и подключения для них тоже. Тем более, если Вы пишите первый большой проект – 146% у Вас будут какие-то косяки, которые приведут к проблемам производительности и без бандла, так что всё решите уже по ходу)